# How to call "Inliers" and "Outliers" in French

Tags: outliers, terminology

I asked this on the French Exchange site, but this is stat related so...

How do you say "Inliers" and "Outliers" (as with RANSAC) in French? The Wikipedia article doesn't translate them, but honestly there should be a translation since there is nothing English-ly-specific about these names.

My guesses are "Inliers = Valeurs (ou données) centrales" and "Outliers = Valeurs (ou données) éloignées"

Comment: Ok, Wikipedia says "Données aberrantes" for Outliers specificly

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted on French Language Stackexchange and answered there: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12321/inliers-and-outliers-in-french